# Cannot adjust input field size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-input

I have tried size attribute and width property individually and separately.
But it doesn't work out.
I want input and textarea of different sizes.
Here are my snippets.

**CSS:**

```
input, textarea{
    margin-left: 12px;
    font-family: segoe ui;
    width: 200;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input name="mail" type="email" class="form-control" id="usrMail" size="20"/>
<textarea name="comment" class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? Beware you have a error..it should be `width: 200px`

Comment: _"I want input and textarea of different sizes"_ - then don't set them both to 200px

Comment: @Sexy Turnip: It was one of my tries.Read initial content properly.

Comment: @ Luis P. A: Yes I've used bootstrap.And in other forms it seems to be no problem in using size attribute.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried - Not post code that would obviously achieve the _opposite_ of your desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `bootstrap` take a look at **[bootstrap forms sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_sizing.asp)**.

**Input Sizing in Forms :**

Set the heights of input elements using classes like `.input-lg` and `.input-sm`.

Set the widths of elements using grid column classes like `.col-lg-*` and `.col-sm-*`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
input, textarea {
  margin-left: 12px;
  font-family: 'segoe ui'; 
}

input {
  width: 200px;
}

textarea {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input name="mail" type="email" class="form-control" id="usrMail" size="20"/>
<br />
<br />
<textarea name="comment" class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
```

Comment: Click on 'Run code snippet' and you will see different size on input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Make your CSS correct. Use 'px'(200px) for width instead of using 200.

```css
input, textarea{
 margin-left: 12px;
 font-family: segoe ui;
 width: 200px;
 /* Put your other CSS here */
}
```

```html
<input name="mail" type="email" class="form-control" id="usrMail" size="20"/>
<br /><br />
<textarea name="comment" class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
```